# unmarshalling file with problems

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have this code that unmarshall a file using a xsd template:

```
String schema = "/META-INF/templates/git60_data_mod1_def.xsd";
isr = new InputStreamReader(GIT60Manager.class.getResourceAsStream(schema));
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = new Unmarshaller(isr, main);
```

this is the xsd file:

```
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
  GIT60 schema Mod 1 (Data)
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>

<xs:include id="git60_mod1_def.xsd" schemaLocation="./git60_mod1_def.xsd" />

<xs:element name="mainData" type="GIT60FileMod1Data" jrb:length="100" />

<xs:complexType name="GIT60FileMod1Data">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="git60Tax" type="GIT60FileTaxMod1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And this is the exception when I run the application:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
at it.assist.jrecordbind.DefinitionLoader$1.fatalError(DefinitionLoader.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext$2.fatalError(ParserContext.java:207)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.includeSchema(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:234)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.includeDecl.action0(includeDecl.java:42)
at    com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.includeDecl.leaveElement(includeDecl.java:114)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.endElement(NGCCRuntime.java:275)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.endElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:546)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.JAXPParser.parse(JAXPParser.java:115)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:337)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:183)
at it.assist.jrecordbind.DefinitionLoader.findSchema(DefinitionLoader.java:107)
at it.assist.jrecordbind.DefinitionLoader.<init>(DefinitionLoader.java:71)
at it.assist.jrecordbind.AbstractUnMarshaller.<init>(AbstractUnMarshaller.java:53)
at it.assist.jrecordbind.Unmarshaller.<init>(Unmarshaller.java:245)
at it.assist.jrecordbind.Unmarshaller.<init>(Unmarshaller.java:263)
at com.samelan.gitim.core.service.io.account.impl.GIT60Manager.doImportMod1GtFile(GIT60Manager.java:1259)
at com.samelan.gitim.core.service.managers.GtFileProcessorManagerTest.testProcFilesNewTemplateGit60(GtFileProcessorManagerTest.java:717)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:341)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:463)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:412)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.JAXPParser.parse(JAXPParser.java:115)
at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:337)
... 55 more
```

Anyone can help me with this issue? Does anyone know what is the problem?
Lot of thanks.

Thank you Perception, but if I do what you said me I have this exception:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
at com.samelan.gitim.core.service.io.account.impl.GIT60Manager.doImportMod1GtFile(GIT60Manager.java:1256)
at com.samelan.gitim.core.service.managers.GtFileProcessorManagerTest.testProcFilesNewTemplateGit60(GtFileProcessorManagerTest.java:717)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: `Unmarshaller unmarshaller = new Unmarshaller(isr, main);` isn't JAXB code.  What does that code do?

Comment: unmarshall a file using a xsd template

Comment: I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead and a member of the JAXB (JSR-222) expert group and I have no idea whay you mean by `unmarshall a file using a xsd template` can you provide additional details?

Comment: I'm sorry Blaise Doughan, I'm going to try to explain you. I have a template "git60_mod1_def.xsd" and a file that I want to parse using Unmarshaller class, but when I try it throw the exception that I put on the post. if you need more information I provide you

Comment: Where does the `Unmarshaller` class come from? What package is it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have schema validation turned on but you did not specify a valid schema URI. I understand by this:

```
/META-INF/templates/git60_data_mod1_def.xsd
```

That you are trying to use a file resource for the schema, you need to indicate as much, with a ***valid*** file URI:

```
file:///META-INF/templates/git60_data_mod1_def.xsd
```

This URI needs to specify the *absolute* path to the file resource (which I assume you don't actually have a root directory called META-INF).

Comment: Thank you Perception, but if I do what you said me I have this exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
at com.samelan.gitim.core.service.io.account.impl.GIT60Manager.doImportMod1GtFile(GIT60Manager.java:1256)
at com.samelan.gitim.core.service.managers.GtFileProcessorManagerTest.testProcFilesNewTemplateGit60(GtFileProcessorManagerTest.java:717)

Comment: Thats a totally different exception - and its being thrown from `GIT60Manager.doImportMod1GtFile`. Are you initializing some kind of reader in that method?

Comment: Yes, isr = new InputStreamReader(GIT60FileMod1.class.getResourceAsStream(schema));

Comment: @snowpulp - please post a separate question. Include the code from `GIT60Manager.doImportMod1GtFile`, and the full exception stack trace. Also, if this answer fixed the original problem, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String schema = "/META-INF/templates/git60_data_mod1_def.xsd";
```

couldn't not be read